# OnClick function in HTML is not working with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .bor
            {
                border-color: blue;
                border-style: inset;
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myfn(var) {
                alert('kalyan');
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName("kalyan").onclick= function() {
                param.innerHTML = "Clicked This ";
                alert(' clicked');
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $t=$_REQUEST['word'];
            require_once('config.php');
            $q="SELECT * FROM products WHERE pname LIKE '$t%'";
            if($result=mysqli_query($connection,$q))
            {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
                    echo " No result Found ";
                else
                {
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div id='kalyan' class="bor">
                            <a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>" onClick="myfn('kalyan')" > 
                                <?php echo $row['pname']." ".$row['pid']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                echo " No result Found ";
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here onclick event is unable to call that myfn() function 
can anyone please help to trace out this error.
I'm using this script for AutoCompletion with PHP

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Salesforce.  Try posting your question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It also has nothing to do with `AJAX`...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.getElementsByTagName("kalyan")`, but you do not have any `<kalyan>` tags. Also, even if your markup did contain this tag, I'm fairly certain you can't just set `onclick` on the returned collection from that selector.